# File format test

Tags: excel, testing, format, vba

I'm creating a program which opens a file in a specified file path, from a long list of files. They all have same name format, but they are not all .xlsx file format, some are .xlsm format.

```
For file = 2 To 200
If RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) = "" Then Exit For 'no more data, end now

        If KeepOpen Then
            'continue as is, because already open
         Else
            Set InBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2), UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)

         End if
 End If
```

I'm trying to make a simple test which would first text file name for .xlsx/.xlsm before trying to open, but can't seem to make it correctly.

Have tried to do error handling, but it will not execute as desired

Comment: Is the code you share vba? please add the related tag if it is

Comment: Does your filename (column B of RefSheet?) not include the file extension, and your problem is you don't know which one to use?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Though, what I really need to test is the format  of the actual file in the folder. It's easy enough to test my path name, but I need to be able to see if the actual file is .xlsx or .xlsm. Then I need to modify the name in column B with .xlsx or .xlsm accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
Set InBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2), UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
```

to

```
Dim fName As String
If Dir(RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2))<>"" Then
    fName = RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2)
ElseIf Dir(RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2) & ".xlsm")<>"" Then
    fName = RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2) & ".xlsm"
Else
    fName = RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2) & ".xlsx"
End If
Set InBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
```

This will first test to see if the filename is valid exactly as it is recorded in column B.  If not, it will see if a file with an "xlsm" extension exists and, if so, use it.  Otherwise it will assume the file has an "xlsx" extension.

An alternative method (which will probably work with csv and txt files as well) would be:

```
Dim fName As String
'The Dir command will just return the filename.extension portion of the first file that matches the specification
fName = Dir(RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2) & ".*")
If fName = "" Then
    'No matching file was found
    MsgBox "File requested (" & RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & RefSheet.Cells(file, 2) & ") does not exist"
Else
    'Concatenate the path and filename.extension together and open the file
    Set InBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=RefSheet.Cells(file, 1) & fName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
End If
```

P.S.  The declaration of fName can be moved to the start of your Sub (or Function) if you prefer to have all your declarations done up-front.